# whats the meaning of "remainingSeconds":XXXX,"type":"ACTIVE" in druid's supervisor's status object?

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

After starting druid when I open druid's console using `http://localhost:8090/console.html` I can see list of all of my supervisors connected with Kafka topics. Then when I click on status of any of supervisor I get following JSON response

> {"id":"test-kafka7","generationTime":"2017-09-25T12:53:44.003Z","payload":{"dataSource":"test-kafka7","topic":"test-kafka2","partitions":1,"replicas":1,"durationSeconds":3600,"activeTasks":[{"id":"index_kafka_test-kafka7_4b18d459ca23552_dpdodphp","startingOffsets":{"0":0},"startTime":"2017-09-25T12:44:34.572Z","remainingSeconds":3050,"type":"ACTIVE","currentOffsets":{"0":0},"lag":{"0":0}}],"publishingTasks":[],"latestOffsets":{"0":0},"minimumLag":{"0":0},"aggregateLag":0,"offsetsLastUpdated":"2017-09-25T12:53:31.617Z"}}

Many times I see `"remainingSeconds": NNN`,`"type":"ACTIVE"` in the status. But I don't understand what the meaning of this type: active and remaining seconds, remaining seconds for what? And sometimes these two keys don't even appear, so I get too much confused why do they appear sometimes and why don't they appear other times, I don't even understand the meaning of those terms. Can anybody please tell me what is the meaning of these keys and why do they appear sometimes and don't appear other times?

Answer (score 1):

The supervisor status is showing you the current status of all the tasks that it is supervising. The "type" and "remainingSeconds" fields are describing a particular task.

Type ACTIVE means that a task is currently consuming data from Kafka. Another possible type is PUBLISHING which means the task is done consuming data from Kafka, and has started publishing it to Druid's shared deep storage.

That brings us to "remainingSeconds", which is the number of seconds remaining before an ACTIVE task will transition to PUBLISHING. Each task has a lifecycle where it starts out ACTIVE, then becomes PUBLISHING, then finishes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Gian for the answer. Could you please give me any link where I could get the docs for keys of the status object. And I had one more doubt that why do some tasks do not get ACTIVE status? like many times I have noticed, if I create 3 tasks, maybe 2 of them would be active and one of them won't have active status forever and neither it consumes my data to druid nor it has the publish status.

Comment: The meaning of the specific fields isn't documented, although it should be; feel free to file an issue for adding docs (or even start it yourself in a PR!).

The tasks that don't have any status (neither ACTIVE nor PUBLISHING) may not have been started up yet. It's possible you don't have sufficient task capacity to run them all?

Comment: yes, I definitely would file the issue requesting them for proper docs for the object. Even I would love to push PL but I'm not confident if my understanding for each key is correct or not. Gian, as you said I may not be having sufficient capacity right? I guess you could be correct and I'm assuming here that you are talking about workers capacity. Could you please direct me to any link or site where I could understand how to increase these workers capacity?